# Computed styles not applied during leave transition

Tags: vue.js

When an element has a computed style, the style changes are not applied if the element is going through a leave transition:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: 1,
    items: [{
        color: 'red'
      },
      {
        color: 'blue'
      },
      {
        color: 'green'
      },
    ],
    tweened: {
      height: 50,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    divStyles() {
      return {
        height: this.tweened.height + 'px',
        background: this.displayed.color,
        'margin-left': this.selected * 100 + 'px',
        width: '100px',
      }
    },
    displayed() {
      return this.items[this.selected - 1]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selected(newVal) {
      function animate() {
        if (TWEEN.update()) {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate)
        }
      }

      new TWEEN.Tween(this.tweened)
        .to({
          height: newVal * 50
        }, 2000)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
        .start()

      animate()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo) {
      todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.colored-div {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.switcher-leave-to,
.switcher-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switcher-enter-to,
.switcher-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switcher-leave-active,
.switcher-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/16.3.5/Tween.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="selected--" :disabled="selected <= 1">
      Previous
    </button>
  <button @click="selected++" :disabled="selected >= 3">
      Next
    </button>
  <span>Selected: {{selected}}</span>
  <transition name="switcher">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" v-if="index + 1 === selected" :key="index" :style="divStyles" class="colored-div" />
  </transition>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/64syzru5/12/

I would expect the leaving element to continue resizing as it fades out, but it doesn't. What can be done to have the computed styles applied to the leaving element during the `leave-active` transition?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using CSS for the transitions, Javascript doesn't execute at each intermediate step. That's a good thing for performance, but it means that the computed properties aren't recomputed. As best as I can tell, though, you're just trying to animate the height. That's easily accomplished in pure CSS. Use a before-leave hook to set it to an initial value via an inline style or CSS variable, and then remove that property in the after-leave hook.

More to the point, though, it looks like your application might be more suitable for a transition-group instead of a simple transition.

Comment: While these values are hardcoded to `50 * selected + 'px'`, the real case has very dynamic height requirements. Using `height: auto` doesn't work with transitions, of course.

Comment: Right. That's why you need to use the before-leave hook. Just measure the actual height (element.clientHeight) and set it to that value. Then remove the property when the transition completes.

Comment: So, how does the `enter-active` transition resize correctly, but the `leave-active` doesn't? They seem like very similar functions, probably some decent code reuse in Vue for them. It seems like when an element is leaving, it's removed from Vue's "watch list", and so computed styles are lost. I haven't tested it yet, but perhaps it loses so computed changes, such as class bindings, model bindings, etc.